# Make div visible when hover

Tags: javascript, css

so I'm trying to make an X button appear and disapear when mouse over on it. Iv'e tried alot of threads over stackoverflow and did not get an answer.

```js
let closeX = document.createElement("button");
closeX.className = "xBtn";
```

```css
.xBtn {
  display: none;
  width: 23px;
  height: 23px;
  background-image: url(img/xIcon.png);
  background-size: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: -183px;
  right: -154px;
}

.xBtn:hover .xBtn {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="xBtn"> Click </button>
```

So correcly what this code does is just not showing the button even when the mouser is over it.
my goal is that the button will be showen everytime the mouse is on it.

Comment: Just use `CSS` => `.xBtn:hover{display: block;}` will work. No need to make a `JS`

Comment: This div is beeing created when some specific function is running, which makes me create it only by JS... I did exacly as you told me... still not working button is exist just not showing up...

Comment: _“my goal is that the button will be showen everytime the mouse is on it”_ - you can not mouse over an element that has `display: none` to begin with, such elements behave as if they weren’t even there at all in most regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the color of the button to opacity 0 with `rgb(0,0,0,0)` or `opacity: 0` and on hover set the original color/opacity, This is the only way I can think of doing it. Beacuse if you set `display: none` or `visibility: hidden` hover wont trigger

```css
button{
  color: rgb(0,0,0,0);
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0);
  border-color: rgb(0,0,0,0);
  /*or*/
  opacity: 0;
}

button:hover{
  border-color: buttonface;
  color: buttontext;
  background-color: buttonface;
  /*or*/
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
-><button>Hello!</button><-
```

Answer (score 1):

If your element is set to `display:none` it will act as if it is not on the page - so no mouseover will be triggered. You could work with opacity, which would allow for a nice fade in animation, or with the visibility property instead.

Also, the selector `.xBtn:hover .xBtn` would only match elements with the `.xBtn`-class WITHIN an element that is hovered with the same class. You want to change this to `.xBtn:hover { ... }` only.

An example to fade in the button on hover would look like this:

```css
.xBtn{
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
.xBtn:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
Hovere there -&gt; <button class="xBtn">
My button
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `hover` css property has no effect on `display:none` element, you can use `opacity` instead. Also you have to append the button in the DOM.

```js
let closeX = document.createElement("button"); 
closeX.textContent = 'Save';
closeX.className = "xBtn";
document.body.append(closeX);
```

```css
.xBtn{
    opacity: 0;
    width: 23px;
    height: 23px;
    background-image: url(img/xIcon.png);
    background-size: 100%;
    position: relative;
    --top: -183px;
    --right: -154px;
}
.xBtn:hover{
   opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once the display is none you can’t go over it.
Cause in display none it’s like if it doesn’t really exist in the page
Change it from `display:none` and `display:block` to `visibility: hidden` and `visibility: visible`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do it the `javascript` way you can use an event of `mouseover` that toggle a `class hide` with an opacity of 0

```js
let closeX = document.createElement("input");
closeX.setAttribute("type", "button");
closeX.setAttribute("value", "button");

document.body.appendChild(closeX);


closeX.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  this.classList.toggle("hide");
});
```

```css
.hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code must work

```
.xBtn {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 23px;
    height: 23px;
    background-image: url(img/xIcon.png);
    position: relative;
}
.xBtn:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```